# Boost hana getting type in a string

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, reflection, decltype

I'm reflecting structures using boost::hana and I'm trying to get the name of members.  My working solution uses a gcc-specific macro and I'd like to replace it with something more generic.

The header which provides the reflection looks a little like this

```
#include <boost/hana.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct ReflectedStruct
{
    virtual void PrintMemberTypes() = 0;
    virtual ~ReflectedStruct(){}
};

template<class T> struct meta {
    static const std::string& get_name() {return T::class_name;}
};

#define TYPE_NAME(type) \
  template<>struct meta<type> { \
    static constexpr const char* class_name = #type; \
    static const char* get_name() {return class_name;} \
  };

TYPE_NAME(double);

#define REFLECT_STRUCT(structure_name, ...)                                                         \
struct structure_name : ReflectedStruct {                                                           \
  BOOST_HANA_DEFINE_STRUCT(structure_name, __VA_ARGS__ );                                           \
  void PrintMemberTypes() {                                                                         \
      boost::hana::for_each(boost::hana::accessors<structure_name>(),                               \
                            [&](auto pair) {                                                        \
                                std::cout                                                           \
                                  << meta< typeof( boost::hana::second(pair)(*this) ) >::get_name() \
                                  << std::endl;                                                     \
                             }                                                                      \
                           );                                                                       \
  }                                                                                                 \
};                                                                                                  \
TYPE_NAME(structure_name);
```

And using it looks like this:

```
REFLECT_STRUCT(Runway,
  (double, lat),
  (double, lon),
  (double, hdg),
  (double, alt)
);

int main()
{
    Runway r;
    r.PrintMemberTypes();  // prints "double, double, double, double"
    return 0;
}
```

My problem is the line which looks like this:

```
meta< typeof( boost::hana::second(pair)(*this) ) >::get_name()
```

More specifically, the problem is the `typeof()` which is gcc-specific.  Here are some things I've tried:

```
// Ok, but gcc-specific.  Resolves to "double"
typeof   ( boost::hana::second(pair)(*this) ) 

// Error, is type "double&", I haven't specialized meta<> for that.
decltype ( boost::hana::second(pair)(*this) )

// error: Doesn't seem to resolve to a type
std::remove_reference<decltype( boost::hana::second(pair)(*this) )>::type

// error: Doesn't seem to resolve to a type
boost::hana::typeid_(boost::hana::second(pair)(*this))::type
```

I need the type to be without the reference. 
I guess the other option would be to specialize `meta<>` for the references instead of the types themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// error: Doesn't seem to resolve to a type
std::remove_reference<decltype( boost::hana::second(pair)(*this) )>::type
```

Since the type of `pair` is basically a template parameter, `type` is a dependent name and so you need to use [`typename`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords):

```
typename std::remove_reference<decltype( boost::hana::second(pair)(*this) )>::type
```

---

```
// error: Doesn't seem to resolve to a type
boost::hana::typeid_(boost::hana::second(pair)(*this))::type
```

You need to keep in mind that `typeid_` returns a value, not a type, so you can't directly use `::type` on its result. You'll need to use `decltype`:

```
typename decltype(boost::hana::typeid_(boost::hana::second(pair)(*this)))::type
```

Comment: You're right.  Both solutions work.  typename was the big thing I was missing.  I'll stick with your hana::typeid_ solution because it will probably better handle any edge cases I haven't thought of yet.